# XAML set image property to values using DependencyProperty

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a model like:

```
{
    "images": [{
        "image_url": "..........",
        "orientation": "horizontal"
    },
    {
        "image_url": "...............",
        "orientation": "vertical"
    }]
}
```

and a ListView DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ImageItem">
    <controls:ImageEx Source="{x:Bind cover_image_url}" PlaceholderSource="" PlaceholderStretch="Uniform"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now, I want the `ImageEx` control's `PlaceholderSource` property change along with `orientation`.

More clearly, when the image property is horizontal, `ImageEx` will load a place holder 1. When the image property is vertical, `ImageEx` will load a place holder 2.

How to do this. Please show me.

Comment: You just want to switch `PlaceholderSource` by image `orientation` property， Right？

Comment: Almost yes, is there any ways, Nico?

Comment: Sure, Please check the below code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> More clearly, when the image property is horizontal, ImageEx will load a place holder 1. When the image property is vertical, ImageEx will load a place holder 2.

You could use [`IValueConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter) interface to approach, use converter class to converter different message type to different PlaceholderSource  for `ImageEx`. You could refer the follow ImageConverter.

```
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        object img = null;

        switch (value.ToString())
        {
            case "horizontal":
                img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/holder1.png"));
                break;
            case "vertical":
                img = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/holder2.png"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return img;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter  x:Key="Converter"/>
</Page.Resources>

       ......

<DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ImageItem">
    <controls:ImageEx Source="{x:Bind cover_image_url}" PlaceholderSource="{x:Bind orientation,Converter={StaticResource Converter}}" PlaceholderStretch="Uniform"/>
</DataTemplate>
```